# writeBin raw() different for 1:3 and c(1,2,3)?

Tags: r

```
> writeBin(1:3, raw(), size=4, endian="little")
 [1] 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
> writeBin(c(1,2,3), raw(), size=4, endian="little")
 [1] 00 00 80 3f 00 00 00 40 00 00 40 40
> writeBin(c(1:3), raw(), size=4, endian="big")
 [1] 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03
> writeBin(c(1,2,3), raw(), size=4, endian="big")
 [1] 3f 80 00 00 40 00 00 00 40 40 00 00
```

The first and third result is what I expect, but why do I get a different raw vector for a vector specified as c(1,2,3)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because one is stored as an integer, and the other as a double:

```
typeof(1:3)
typeof(c(1,2,3))
typeof(c(1L,2L,3L))
```