# Difference in representation a double number in hex between R and MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab, octave, endianness

On the same machine R and MATLAB produce different hex representations of doubles, e.g.
R:

```
x <- 2.28
writeBin(x,raw(0))
```

gives

```
3d 0a d7 a3 70 3d 02 40
```

MATLAB:

```
x = 2.28;
num2hex(x)
```

gives

```
40023d70a3d70a3d
```

Octave produces the same result as MATLAB. Why is MATLAB's output reversed?

Update: So it's indeed the endianness. It remains to find out why R gets it wrong. Using an example from chappjc's answer below I get following output on a little-endian CPU:

```
writeBin(1024, raw(), endian='little')
00 00 00 00 00 00 90 40
```

and

```
writeBin(1024, raw(), endian='big')
40 90 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

which is exactly the opposite of what I would have expected.
Is it wrong output from R or misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB on Intel systems stores floating point values as little endian. Use [`computer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/computer.html) to check:

```
>> [computerType, ~, endian] = computer
computerType =
PCWIN64
endian =
L
```

You can use [`swapbytes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) to convert between little an big-endian:

```
>> num2hex(1024)
ans =
4090000000000000
>> num2hex(swapbytes(1024))
ans =
0000000000009040
```

In R, specify `endian="big"` (or `endian="little"`) in `writeBin` to match your MATLAB:

```
writeBin(x,raw(0),endian="big")
```

Comment: I get 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 40 out of that R command. This is obviously big endian. Any idea?

Comment: @user3499473 With `num2hex(1024)`? Then `computer` probably returns `B`. Is that right? That should give you a programmatic way to determine your endianness. What platform are you on?

Comment: With 1024, yes. The endianness according to computer is "L". I'm on Core-i7 x64.
MATLAB: num2hex(1024) => 4090000000000000.
R: writeBin(1024,raw(0),endian="little") => 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 40.
Something is wrong with R's output, right?

Comment: @user3499473 Interesting. Operating system?

Comment: I'm reproducing the same behavior on Core-i7 x64 Ubuntu 13.10 and Core-i5 x64 Windows 8.1.

Comment: @user3499473 Maybe I gave you the wrong R syntax for writing little endian.  I don't have R, but it seems to work like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263254/writebin-raw-different-for-13-and-c1-2-3). Perhaps the `endian` option only applies when writing _to a file_?

Comment: Writing to and reading from a binary file has the same behaviour.

Comment: @user3499473 My guess would be that `raw` is chopping the value into bytes (i.e. 8-bit pieces) where endianness does not apply. I don't know the use of `writeBin`... Perhaps you need to add `size=8` (if `x` is a double) to actually change the byte order?

Answer (score 2):

This is [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Few people know that this is an actual word. Now you are one of them.

Comment: So the assumption that MATLAB and R would use CPU's endianness is wrong?